# How can i add the properties of the pose position to the rest poseition

Tags: armature, pose-mode

The problem is not complicated but i dont know how to do it, i just wanna copy the properties of my pose position of an object and change or copy the properties to the rest position, because the position i have is the one i want in the rest position and not in the pose position. If someone can help me

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, if you mean that you want to change the rest position of the object, duplicate the Armature modifier, disable the first one, change the pose, apply the second Armatue modifier, now the object has its shape changed, re-enable the first Armature modifier?

Comment: @moonboots I want to make so the pose position i have is the rest position

Comment: If you're talking about the armature only, change its pose then in Pose mode go into the top menu > Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose, is it what you want?

Comment: @moonboots Yeah it works, but the mesh is in the same place :(

Comment: Please see my answer and tell if it works

Comment: It works, awesome thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pose of your armature as wanted, keep it in *Pose* mode. Duplicate your *Armature* modifier:

[image]

Now you have 2 modifiers, disable the first one, apply the second one:

[image]

Re-enable the first one, the mesh will go crazy but don't pay attention:

[image]

Now go into *Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose* and it should work:

[image]